How to convert an Ansible list to a list of dictionaries adding the same key:value per item
So I have a list of AWS Instance IDs:
ok: [localhost] => {
    "instance_running.instance_ids": [
        "i-05a765076f4cbf03b",
        "i-096b8a656d875f38a",
        "i-0b5156565ac17c9e4",
        "i-0865656657565edd5"
    ]
}

And I want to assign it to a dict variable to use in the targets parameter. The port is the same for all the ids and is another variable:
targets:
  - Id: "{{ instance_id }}"
    Port: "{{ host_port }}"

I am confused by the map function and the community.general.dict

I misread your question; you're not looking to create a dict variable; you're looking to create a list in which each item is a dictionary.

Given the variables
  host_port: 80
  instance_running:
    instance_ids:
      - i-05a765076f4cbf03b
      - i-096b8a656d875f38a
      - i-0b5156565ac17c9e4
      - i-0865656657565edd5

There are many options on how to create targets
  targets:
  - Id: i-05a765076f4cbf03b
    Port: 80
  - Id: i-096b8a656d875f38a
    Port: 80
  - Id: i-0b5156565ac17c9e4
    Port: 80
  - Id: i-0865656657565edd5
    Port: 80


You can use either the filter community.general.dict_kv

  ids: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
           map('community.general.dict_kv', 'Id') }}"

, or community.general.json_query
  ids: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
           community.general.json_query('[].{Id: @}') }}"

to create a list of dictionaries
  ids:
  - Id: i-05a765076f4cbf03b
  - Id: i-096b8a656d875f38a
  - Id: i-0b5156565ac17c9e4
  - Id: i-0865656657565edd5


Then, create a product of the lists and combine the items

  targets: "{{ ids |
               product([{'Port': host_port}]) |
               map('combine') }}"


The next option is the filter community.general.dict

  targets: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
               product([host_port]) |
               map('zip', ['Id', 'Port']) |
               map('map', 'reverse') |
               map('community.general.dict') }}"


But, the easiest option is to create the below query

  _query: '[].{Id: @, Port: `{{ host_port }}`}'
  targets: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
               community.general.json_query(_query) }}"



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: all

  vars:

    host_port: 80
    instance_running:
      instance_ids:
        - i-05a765076f4cbf03b
        - i-096b8a656d875f38a
        - i-0b5156565ac17c9e4
        - i-0865656657565edd5

    ids1: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
              map('community.general.dict_kv', 'Id') }}"
    ids2: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
              community.general.json_query('[].{Id: @}') }}"
    target1: "{{ ids1 |
                 product([{'Port': host_port}]) |
                 map('combine') }}"
    target2: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
                 product([host_port]) |
                 map('zip', ['Id', 'Port']) |
                 map('map', 'reverse') |
                 map('community.general.dict') }}"
    _query: '[].{Id: @, Port: `{{ host_port }}`}'
    target3: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids |
                 community.general.json_query(_query) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ids1
    - debug:
        var: ids2

    - debug:
        var: target1
    - debug:
        var: target2
    - debug:
        var: target3



The simplest solution seems to be just to construct a list of dicts in a loop:
---
- name: Assign the variable
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    instance_running:
      instance_ids: [
        "i-05a765076f4cbf03b",
        "i-096b8a656d875f38a",
        "i-0b5156565ac17c9e4",
        "i-0865656657565edd5"
      ]
    host_port: 22
  tasks:
    - name: Generate the list of dicts
      set_fact:
        targets: "{{ targets | default([]) + [{ 'id': item, 'port': host_port }] }}"
      loop: "{{ instance_running.instance_ids }}"

    - name: Show the result
      debug:
        var: targets

The result would be as follows:
TASK [Show the result] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  targets:
  - id: i-05a765076f4cbf03b
    port: 22
  - id: i-096b8a656d875f38a
    port: 22
  - id: i-0b5156565ac17c9e4
    port: 22
  - id: i-0865656657565edd5
    port: 22

